# Testing component method with dispatch() inside it

Tags: reactjs, integration-testing

I want to test **submit()** function, but I don't know how to do it after searching and reading lots of posts.

I found out how to test component's lifecyle methods, render() function but not for submit(). I'm using enzyme, sinon, jest for testing.

```
export class ChangePassword extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  submit() {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    this.setState({clicked: true});
    let userId = GeneralHelper.userId();
    let {currentPassword, newPassword} = this.props.form.changePasswordForm.values;
    let data = {
      currentPassword,
      newPassword
    };
    dispatch(changePassword(userId, data));
    dispatch(reset('changePasswordForm'));
  }

  render() {
      <ChangePasswordForm onSubmit={this.submit}/>
  }
}

ChangePassword.propTypes = {};
ChangePassword.defaultProps = {};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChangePassword);
```